# ST_TRANSFORM SDE Oracle does not convert the geometry

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I try to convert a geometry from 31370 to 3857. But it does not work. The coordinates stay in 31370.

DB: Oracle 11

ArcSDE: 10.4.1

The code:

```
select 
sde.st_srid(shape) 
,sde.st_x(shape) as X_lambert
,sde.st_y(shape) as Y_lambert
,sde.st_x(sde.st_transform(shape, 31370, 3857 ) ) as X_pmercator
,sde.st_y(sde.st_transform(shape, 31370, 3857 ) ) as Y_pmercator
from usersde.cst
;
```

The datas:
[image]

Comment: Your syntax appears to be incorrect. The Oracle usage is `sde.st_transform (g1 sde.st_geometry, srid integer, geogtrans_id integer)` but 3857 is not a geogtrans ID. You want 3857 in the `srid` term, and the correct transform ID for 31370 to 3857 datum conversion in the geogtrans_id position

Comment: Hi @Vince, i don't understand your last statement. Could you give an exemple? 
Maybe it's 102113  WGS_1984_Web_Mercator
Thank you.

Comment: No, a transformation is not a projection, it's a rule for converting between datums. I don't have the list anywhere nearby, and won't anytime soon. Contact Tech Support.